# finding li elements dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get some `<li>` elements dynamically generated from a javascript function in this way:

```
function readPicture(file){
    if (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var randomNumberText = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('.past').append('<li><img data-whatever="'+e.target.result+'" id="picture'+randomNumberText+'"/></li>');
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

}
```

On a click event I'm trying to get those li elements this way:

```
$('#body').on('click','#upload',function(){
     $('.past').find('li').each(function(){
          console.log('ok');
     });
});
```

**The HTML**

```
<button id="upload">ok</button>
<div class="photo_attach">
    <ul class="past"></ul>
</div>
```

The fact that the li elements are automatically generated it's the origin of the issue. So anyone to give me some alternatives

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Why do you think that dynamic generation is the reason? There are actually no `li`s in your `.part` in your HTML.

Comment: Are you that `body` has the `id` `#body`?

Comment: No @Azim, it was a mistake i removed it.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev have look into the javascript function

Comment: @PraveenKumar to get the li elements dynamically generated from the javascript function that i post

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is in the following line since the other code just seems ok:

```
$('#body').on('click','#upload',function(){
```

Should be :

```
$('body').on('click','#upload',function(){
```

Remove `#` from body selector and it will work.

```js
$('.past').append('<li>First item</li><li>Second item</li><li>Third item</li>');

$(function(){
     $('body').on('click', '#upload',function(){
         $('.past').find('li').each(function(){
             console.log('ok');
         });
     });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="upload">ok</button>
    <div class="photo_attach">
   <ul class="past">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe it is located in a div with id body you should clarify this before posting an answer

Comment: No, it was a mistake, i removed the # tag, but the problem still the same

Comment: Okay @KubiRoazhon you can see in the answer that if the `li`s are correctely appanded so the code work just fine.

Comment: the li elements there are not present in the moment of the body loading so they are automatically generated, for jquery it's normal to not find them. am I clear enough?

Comment: If you're defining the click event inside the ready function so no it's not normal to not find them if you click after the DOM is ready the function should find them, you can notice that my example also add the `li`s dynamically so _there are not present in the moment of the body loading_ also but i can find them.

Comment: Just make sure that you're calling `readPicture` before click so the `li`s are present when you click.

Comment: Yes, I call read picture before clicking the button. I can understand your example, but I don't know why it's still not working. The DOM is loaded one time in the page loading so my elements are added after that ! ! =/

Comment: Check if there's any message in console.

Comment: No there's no message

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(document).on('click','#upload',function(){
```

instead of

```
$('#body').on('click','#upload',function(){
```

**UPDATE**

Please have a look at following fiddle. Its working fine there. Might be no `<li>s` are added, or click is not working in your code.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/r9mwz816/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
        $('.past').append("<li><img data-whatever='' id='picture"+i+"'>"+i+"    </li>");
    }

    $(document).on('click','#upload',function(){
        $('.past').find('li').each(function(){
        console.log('ok');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It was a mistake, this not the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When appending a new li with JavaScript put extra effort to add a class say `dynamic-li`

then getting them back will be much easier as

```
$('.past').find('li.dynamic-li')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your code like this : `$( this ).find('.past li').each(function(){`